# Meaning of "Anything for you"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Sometimes I think it means *I love you* but sometimes I hear this expression in non-lovely situations.

for example:

> A: Mr. Corlone, I’m really sorry to trouble you, but I need your help.
>   B: **Anything for you**, Charlie! Your father was like a
>   brother to me.

two men are talking in this example so this is not a lovely situation or falling in love  :)

another example:

> A: Thank you soo much you're the sweetest.
>    B: Anything for you

so what does this expression actually means?

Comment: It's equivalent to “[I’ll do] anything for you”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Anything for you" is an abbreviated form of

> I'd do anything for you.

It means someone is willing to go to any lengths to make you happy. If you hear it, it means you're very special to the person who says it, for whatever reason: family connection, you're a great friend, you did them a favor, whatever.

Answer (score 2):

It does not necessarily mean "love". The expression "anything for you" can cover all the other positive attitudes, such as :

1. Support : That covers your godfather example.
2. Affection : This covers your second example. Note how "A" here initiates the positivity by saying "B" is the sweetest. B is simply returning the positivity.

Another thing I want to mention here is that the word "Love" itself can have two general levels of meaning, depending on context :

1. "Romantic" Love : this is your Boy meets girl (or boy), they want to go on a date, and have sex and so on and so forth type love.
2. Strong preference : For example, among three flavors of icecreams, I may "like" vanilla and chocolate, but I "love" strawberry.